# Add all values together SQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I add all the `amounts` together so that instead of this select script returning all the individual withdrawal amounts return one number of them all added together?

```
<?php
$end_date = strtotime($nextdate);
$start_date = strtotime($statement_date);
$username = $usr['username'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `usr_withdraw` WHERE `timestamp` > '$start_date' AND `timestamp` < '$end_date' AND `username` = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());

while($balance = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 
    echo $balance['amount'];
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the structure of your usr_withdraw table? Probably what you'll have to do is select SUM(name_of_the_value_field).

Comment: You mean you want to echo everything together instead of echoing all one for each row?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida the name of the column which has all the amounts is called `amount`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes instead of echoing each amount I want to echo them all added together. so at the moment is echoing out like this `5,4,7` instead I would want it to echo out like this `16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only 1 row with the aggregate sum of all amounts use the sql [`sum()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function.

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM `usr_withdraw` WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thankyou and then I'm assuming I still echo it out the same and use the same while correct? Thankyou for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `usr_withdraw` WHERE `timestamp` > '$start_date' AND `timestamp` < '$end_date' AND `username` = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
```

But also keep in mind that these mysql_* functions are out of PHP from version 7 on, then your code will be soon out of date. The ideal is using mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Comment: Thankyou very useful.

Comment: You're welcome. If you enjoyed the answer, please accept it, ok?